# Issue with format variable

Tags: java, sql

```
String name = tabProduit[i];
for(int a=0;a<objetTerminal.length;a++){

ter.setCrimpkontakt(objetTerminal[a]);

if(objetTerminal[a].equals(name)){

List<Terminal> listTerminalDq = (List<Terminal>)session.createQuery( "select
dq from Terminal where crimpkontakt="+name).list();  

String[] objetDQ = (String[]) listTerminalDq.toArray(new 

String[listTerminalDq.size()]);
```

For example if name equals 708-681-001 and when i execute my code objetDQ.length i get 0; because name became 708-681-1 so how can i solve it plz ??

Comment: "if(objetTerminal[a].equals(nom))" what is nom here?

Comment: i made a mistake it is name

Comment: there is no possibilities in string to became this format place your whole code tabProductit[i] will become this format so check what tabProductit returns.

Comment: tabProduit contains the correct format like  708-681-001

Comment: `String name = tabProduit[i]`.. is this the place where name gets changes?  Please  confirm, as rest of the snippet don't have code which may change name value.

Comment: yes; you are right. the value of name is changing en fonction of "i"; thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
List<Terminal> listTerminalDq = (List<Terminal>)session.createQuery( "select
dq from Terminal where crimpkontakt='"+name+"'").list();
```